# autoload a class within a module

Tags: ruby

In a gem I have a file

```
#/lib/my_gem/dym/proximity.rb
module MyGem
   module Dym
     class Proximity
     end
   end
end
```

I am trying to autoload this with

```
module MyGem
   autoload 'Dym::Proximity', "my_gem/dym/proximity"
end
```

which gives an error to the effect that

```
NameError: autoload must be constant name: Dym::Proximity
```

or I also tried

```
module MyGem
   autoload :Dym::Proximity, "my_gem/dym/proximity"
end
```

which gives

```
TypeError: :Dym is not a class/module
```

and in anycase `:Dym::Proximity` is not a well formed symbol.

How do I do this?

Comment: `:` means symbol. How about `::Dym::Proximity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only autoload one module level at a time, so you need to introduce a intermediary file.

The way I got this to work was by introducing a file called `lib/my_gem/dym.rb` that autoloads proximity:

```rb
# console.rb
require_relative 'lib/my_gem'
```

```rb
# lib/my_gem.rb
module MyGem
  autoload :Dym, "./lib/my_gem/dym.rb"

  puts "The Dym::Proximity module isn't yet loaded!"
  Dym::Proximity
  puts "The Dym::Proximity module has been successfully loaded!"
end
```

```rb
# lib/my_gem/dym.rb
module MyGem
  module Dym
    autoload :Proximity, "./lib/my_gem/dym/proximity.rb"
  end
end
```

```rb
# lib/my_gem/dym/proximity.rb
module MyGem
  module Dym
    class Proximity
      puts 'Dym::Proximity module is loading!'
    end
  end
end
```

With the following files I get the following output:

```sh
ruby console.rb
The Dym::Proximity module isn't yet loaded!
Dym::Proximity module is loading!
The Dym::Proximity module has been successfully loaded!
```

So you see even though you had to introduce a intermediary file you can use multiple module levels now and they will cascade and autoload.

Comment: Nice example. The trick here is you can only auto-load one level at a time.